# APK incompatible with older version

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to install the APK I compiled from Android Studio but it seems like the APK generated is not compatible. Below is the image for my settings:

Properties
http://prntscr.com/ef0rjs

Flavors:
http://prntscr.com/ef0rr6

The phone im installing the APK is Lollipop 5.1

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show here your Android Manifest or build.gradle?

just install the versions in your SDK Manager :)

but try this one in your build.gradle set your minSDK to lollipop

```
compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app_name"
        minSdkVersion 16 //change it to the version of lollipop :)
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```